# Passing a string as a prop and using it to make a class name in Svelte

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, svelte

I have this BigButton component where I want to pass a bgColor prop :

```js
<BigButton
        title="Join a Game"
        description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, est?"
        icon="star"
        bgColor="blue-500"
    />
```

then on the component I handle it in the onMount hook:

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    export let title: string;
    export let description: string = '';
    export let icon: string;
    export let bgColor: string | undefined;
    let iconUrl: string;

    onMount(() => {
        if (icon) iconUrl = `/icons/${icon}@2x.png`;
        if (bgColor) bgColor = `bg-${bgColor}`;
    });
</script>

<div
    class="flex flex-row w-96 rounded-3xl p-6 
    justify-center place-items-center {bgColor ? bgColor : 'bg-slate-400'}"
>
```

the component renders with the class name but the style is not applied.

I did something similar with the icon prop, which does work:

```js
<img src={iconUrl} alt="gold star" />
```

Comment: Are you saying that in the **rendered** page, the class for that div exactly `flex flex-row w-96 rounded-3xl p-6 justify-center place-items-center bg-blue-500`

Comment: Yes! It renders like that

Comment: perhaps the CSS for `bg-blue-500` is broken ... what does that look like

Comment: It's not, it's tailwind : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color . I've tested hard coding `bg-blue-500` in as well

Comment: if you add the class to that element in browser developer tools inspector - does it work

Comment: what if you pass in `bgColor="bg-blue-500"` and remove the `if (bgColor) bgColor = \`bg-${bgColor}\`;` code? just wondering, shouldn't make a difference ... but ... coding sux :p

Comment: "I've tested hard coding" did that work?

Comment: It works, both of your questions, I guess that's what I'll end up doing.

Comment: weird .. I'd still be tempted to investigate why your code doesn't work ... if the element ends up with the exact same class, it shouldn't matter how it got there

Comment: also, not sure it's valid syntax, but `class="flex flex-row w-96 rounded-3xl p-6 justify-center place-items-center bg-{bgColor || 'slate-400'}"` - then you can also remove the `if (bgColor) bgColor = \`bg-${bgColor}\`;`

Comment: @Bravo: That if statement serves to prefix with `bg-`, not set a default. But `bgColor ? bgColor : 'bg-slate-400'` could be replaced with `bgColor ?? 'bg-slate-400'`. `||` should not be used on things other than actual booleans unless you want to potentially run into very stupid bugs due to how JavaScript converts objects to `boolean`.

Comment: so true @H.B. didn't think fully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Tailwind, this relies heavily on post-processing of the code. My guess would be that if you do not include the full class name, the corresponding CSS will not be included in the output, because including every possible Tailwind class would create a massive file.

If you know what classes will be possible, you can also try to [force the inclusion of those styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes).

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely it!, thanks!