# Why is the curly braces substitution not working with tailwindcss here?

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to create a svelte component whose color is a variable. But on the final render while the component does have the class name, the color does not render. Why is this happenning and how can I fix this.

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let color: string;
</script>

<div id="solus" class="absolute overflow-hidden bg-{color}-600 h-96 w-96 rounded-full blur-3xl" />
```

I tried swapping the curly braces and wrote if-else statements but that is inefficient and I need it to render any color I choose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a string as a prop and using it to make a class name in Svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72836163/passing-a-string-as-a-prop-and-using-it-to-make-a-class-name-in-svelte)

Answer (score 0):

I saw about [arbitrary values for background color](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#arbitrary-values), you just need to add the color between two square brackets.

```
<div class="bg-[#50d71e]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

For your case, you need to do a string interpolation. Your code will be something like this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let CUSTOM_BG_COLOR: string;
</script>
...

<div class={`bg-[${CUSTOM_BG_COLOR}]`}>
  <!-- Content -->
</div>
```